# Import Error - No module named requests - Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have problem with Django 1.8.2 on virtualenv with Python 2.7

i installed requests with `pip install requests` successfully. I'm able to start `python` and `import requests` - it is working.

But when i start my django app in venv with uwsgi - when i enter website i see error:

```
ImportError at /pobieraniebot/
No module named requests
```

When Django app is working in the same virtual environment as i run python.

Comment: maybe you installed outside of your virtualenv?

Comment: Are you sure that "Django app is working in the same virtual environment"? Can you verify it? Can you show your wsgi file? Have you installed requests in the correct virtualenv? Can you `pip freeze` to check?

Comment: Check your uwsgi configuration if you are daemonizing the worker. maybe add your uwsgi.ini to the question if so. Also the output of  `pip freeze` might be illuminating

Comment: Show your view.py file.  Run manage.py shell.  Then import requests.  If that works, you may have not properly imported in your view

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you executed `pip install requests` in your virtual env.

Comment: Yes, i executed this in virtual env. `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in ./venv2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. I created test.py file with `import requests` and it is working

Comment: but does you django app. too reside in the same virtual env. ? Also, hope you have not missed out to activate the virtual env.

Comment: This should be a comment not answer. Wait until you have enough reputation to leave comments.

Comment: @IanAuld Ok Sir, Thanks for pointing that out ! Will be careful next time !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov I am aware of the fact that it does not provide an answer to the question & it is more or less a comment. I apologized for it & said I will keep the point in mind ! Thanks for pointing it out again ! :)